# How to pass event from Android to Glass and vise versa?

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

Is it possible to pass events from Android to Glass and vise versa?

By event I understand command that could have some data. Like intents concept of android.

Comment: In general yes (since they're both computers), but do you have any concrete examples? Your question is a bit too broad to provide a specific answer.